# nginx redirect to domain when user enters IP address

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-20.04

I have several domains configured for my websites on my VPS.

What I want to achieve is: If a user enters the IP address of my VPS directly on his/her browser, like this: `https://X.X.X.X`, I want it to redirect to one of my websites.

I was able to make it work for HTTP (`http://X.X.X.X`) like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  IP_OF_MY_VPS;

    return       301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

However, if the user enters `https://X.X.X.X`, it doesn't work. Can someone please help out ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a valid `https` block for the IP address.

However, since you cannot get certificates which can be used with an IP address, you will be left with a URL that gives a SSL error from the browser.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2043617 and for example https://www.ssl.com/faqs/order-ssl-tls-certificate-for-ip-address/ seem to indicate that it really depends on the CA if they will issue a certificate for an IP-address but there isn't anything technical that actually prevents them from issuing one.

Comment: Is there any other way then to redirect the user to my website when they enter the ip address directly in to the browser ? Because my website already has SSL to it. I just need to redirect user when they try to enter the IP address directly in the browser

Comment: You need to have a certificate that lists the IP address in Subject Alternate Name field, along with your website's domain name. Your current certificate likely contains the domain name only.

Answer (score 1):

It's because HTTPS uses port 443. So just add another `listen` statement like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443;
    server_name  IP_OF_MY_VPS;

    return       301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It gives me an error when i perform nginx -t :

nginx: [emerg] no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed. I don't want to setup ssl again since my website already has ssl configured. I just want to redirecto the website.

Comment: Sorry I didn't think so much in advance, try adding `ssl off;`

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: Interesting, just tried it out and it works for me.

Comment: I got the deprecated warning and an error statement. Can you provide the whole conf file please ?

Comment: I just copy pasted your config and replaced the IP placeholder with actual IP address.

Comment: When you go on https://IP_OF_VPS does it redirect you to the domain ?

Comment: For the first time the browser showed me an SSL error, but after telling it to go to the page it redirected fine. I think because Nginx served my main certificate for that request too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117488/discussion-between-noel-nemeth-and-mervin-hemaraju).